# jQuery/Javascript: Check all checkboxes but within a specific table only

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Just needing a little help here. To start off, here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<div>
<table id="table" width="100%">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" />Select All</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

There's 5 more tables like this in a single page and what I'm meaning to do is that when the `<th>` checkbox is ticked on a certain table, only the `<td>` checkboxes within that certain table will be checked. Any help on how this will be done would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get bind a `change` event handler to all checkboxes that are descendants of a `th` element, and then check all checkboxes that are descendants of the closest `table`:

```
$("th :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7eGtx/4/) with 2 tables. If you want the checkbox in the `th` to uncheck all the other checkboxes too, then you can do this, using the second argument of `prop` (thanks @SalmanA):

```
$("th :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: You can eliminate the if-else by `... .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));`

Comment: @SalmanA - Good call. I've edited the answer to use that instead. I always forget that one :)

Comment: @James Does it matter if I have my tables wrapped in a div?

Comment: @MikeSanchez - No, that won't make any difference. The `th :checkbox` selector only cares about checkboxes in `th` elements, and the `closest` method will find the closest `table` and go no futher.

Comment: @James Thanks for the help, buddy. I was using an outdated jQuery file which made it not work. It's all working now. Again, thanks.

Comment: @MikeSanchez - No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Comment: @JamesAllardice, just a follow up. Let's say the checkboxes to be checked are on a different table, the next table to be specific, what do I need to change? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below jquery

```
$('input[Type="checkbox"]', $('#tableID')).prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#table input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

To bind this event for each checkbox in the `th` tags (as in James Allardice's answer)

```
$('th :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(':checkbox', $(this).closest('table')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: I think the OP wants it to apply separately to all of his 5 tables. This will only work for `#table`.