# jQuery/Javascript: Check all checkboxes on the following table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My original javascript was:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("th :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
 });
});
```

which was used on a setting like this:

```
<div>
<table id="table" width="100%">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" />Select All</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I slightly changed how my tables were and it now goes something like:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" />select all</th>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What do I need to change in my javascript so that when the checkbox in `<th>` is checked, all the checkboxes inside the `<td>`'s in the next table are checked?

Thanks.

[Related to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900830/jquery-javascript-check-all-checkboxes-but-within-a-specific-table-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to `.closest("table")`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("th :checkbox").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("table").next().find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
 });
});
```

`$(this).closest("table")` selects the table of the element matching `th :checkbox`. [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selects the next element, which is another table, in this case.

This code can break easily. I suggest to set an ID to the other table, and use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("th :checkbox").change(function() {
    $("#id-of-table :checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
 });
});
```

Comment: Tables will be generated from data in MySQL. Would that still work?

Comment: *Tables* or *rows*? If there's only one table, the code works. Otherwise, you have to use: `$(this).closest("table").nextAll("table")`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, @Rob W. You've been a great help.